# git push command not notifying about new branch

Tags: git

Consider the following common case:

1. create a new branch with `git branch -b new-branch`
2. do some changes to code
3. commit changes with `git add . && git commit -m "stuff"`
4. push with `git push` (not here I did not add `-u` option)

The output of step 4 is:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

git does not notify me about this being a new branch and it is not pushed yet. On my other devices it print a message, and suggests that I do a `git push --origin ...something`

How to configure git to show that message again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-u` or `--add-upstream` option adds a (tracking) reference in your project's `.git/config` file.  If you want it to show that message, then you should track it.

If you do not track it, it will not know where to look to give you that message.

Without telling it where to push, when you have not set the tracking reference, it can not know where you would want to push it while being on that branch.

The following options may be helpful for this situation as well:

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

or perhaps:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

This should then tell Git to push the current branch to a branch with the same name on the remote repository.

I think run `git push` on a new branch, Git will suggest the full command to push the branch.

Comment: That was not my question, the `git push` command without `-u` should print an output suggesting to use `-u`, and the exit code will probably not be 0 as well. In my case it does nothing, just says `Everything up-to-date` giving me a false sense of security, and I lost multiple days work because of this.

Comment: "git does not notify me about this being a new branch and it is not pushed yet." I believe that this is the key part of the question, how is it meant to know until you tell it to track the branch?

Comment: In other words, everything on the remote and what it knows about is up to date, until you tell it otherwise.  Sorry to hear about the lost days of work, that is pretty awful!

Comment: Ok, your answer is not what exactly what I asked for, but it is a better solution, now it just pushes. Thanks.

Comment: The strange thing is, in another device, and maybe another version of git, it does not print the same output